# Visual Studio Code: 'Ctrl +P' missing git?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Running the latest version of VSCode and Git for Windows.

Whenever I try to use Ctrl+P to use any git command, I get "no results found."

Some of the git commands appear in CTRL+SHIFT+P, however this does not allow me to checkout a branch easily

On the action bar, I have the "Source Control" button, but not a specific git button.

Comment: With the new version of VSCode out. I have found the reason for this.

The newer versions of VSCode use the new Source Control functions. It's enabled by default. I have run 'SCM: Disable Preview SCM' in CTRL+SHIFT+P. This has switched it back to the old git features, which match all the documentation on the vscode site. I guess the new git extension needs some work to bring it up to the old one, and the doco needs to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

Coming from other IDEs, I find this Visual Studio way of working with GIT strange.

These are the steps I manage to make it clone the repository:

- open VSC
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
- scroll to GIT: Clone
- type the clone URL as suggested
- type the clone local folder
- when suggested, click on the top on the *open cloned project*
- enjoy